# rules to define an error code?

Tags: c#, error-code

I'm working on a project in which I need to return error codes in case work failed.
But which is the 'rule' for doing this?

For example:

```
if(tryDoUpload() == false) {
  //upload failed
 int UPLOAD_FAILED = 0x0;
}
```

see `0x0`, is there a pattern to set this error code or can I set any?

I hope this is clear.

Comment: This question is unclear and sounds like it is missing some vital pieces of information such as what KIND of "errorcode" and in what DOMAIN it's used and how it's returned, etc.

Comment: Are you looking for a standard pattern to follow when creating your own custom error codes? Or are you looking for something in the .NET library (because you tagged this with C#)?

Comment: In the snippet you posted, the "error code" should be the result of `tryDoUpload()`. Error codes should indicate a reason there was an error; if you're just returning whether it worked or not, a boolean (`TRUE/FALSE`) works perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is no standard set of error codes for you to use. you are free to make your own.  that being said, error codes are not very user friendly.  if you are using a piece of software what would YOU want to see: "upload failed, error code 0x00deadbeef" or "upload failed, a file with that name all ready exists." you should prefer to give the user meaningful error messages.

Comment: Error codes are not typically for the user to see. They're used in the code itself. See `HRESULT` in Windows COM for an example.

Comment: yup, but they display them anyhow. blue screens, event logs, all over the place i am seeing error codes in windows. in the original post, he was displaying to the user.

Comment: Didn't see original post displaying to user with `Response.Write` (although that may not have been to the user - it could have been for development only). Reversed my downvote of your answer. :)